# Add a new type to an existing prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi there is a way to add a new type to an existing prop?

```
export interface ICustomState extends INonIdealStateProps {
  icon: 'load';
}

export const CustomState: React.FunctionComponent<ICustomState> = (
  props: ICustomState
) => {
//My code
};
```

I have my custom interface `ICustomState` that extends `INonIdealStateProps` and I'm trying to add a new type to the `icon` prop
that already exists in `INonIdealStateProps` but I'm getting this error:

> Interface 'ICustomState' incorrectly extends interface 'INonIdealStateProps'.

The original type is:

```
icon?: IconName | Element
```

Comment: What is the definition of `IconName` ?

Comment: Is a list of string like 'add', 'coffee', etc...
https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a derived interface your properties can be more specific. So for example if `IconName` is just an alias for `string` this would be valid:

```
type IconName = string
export interface INonIdealStateProps {
  icon: IconName | Element
}
export interface ICustomState extends INonIdealStateProps {
  icon: 'load' | Element;
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgxgewHYDkCGBbaBeKBnYAJwEskBzAKAgA8wFDgpTgJCAzNOaGFZGAEwhoANgGVgaFgAVCCMHigBvClCaIkALljr0WKAB8oAUWEQsSYBQC+VWvUbNWHLrADCAVwIIM4ydBosSPwKPHyCIr7SsvJKKmrIWgDkwgho-IkGxqbmwADc1hRAA)

If `IconName` is not  an alias for `string` then you can't really extend the interface in it's current form (this would break the rule that a sub-interface is assignable to the base interface). You could however omit the problematic member from the interface and add it with the new type (although the resulting interface will not be assignable to the `INonIdealStateProps` interface)

```
type IconName = "a" | "b"
export interface INonIdealStateProps {
  icon: IconName | Element
}
export interface ICustomState extends Omit<INonIdealStateProps, 'icon'> {
  icon: 'load' | INonIdealStateProps['icon']; // | INonIdealStateProps['icon'] adds back the type in the base interface, this is not strictly needed
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgxgewHYDkCGBbaBeKAiNPKAH3wCM8AoCADzAQCdgoBLJYCBgMzTmhhTIYAEwhoANgGVgaDgAUGCMAGcoAb0pRWiJAC5YO9FhJQAouIhZ2lAL7U6jZmw7de-AMIBXZcAQZpstC0HEjCqgDyGCzAADwCQqISAfKKKgA0UADkLDqZAHzqmtrI+pniCGjCmSbxSCJiUjIpSsoA2tm5ALoA3FAA9H01gnWJjYEKLe05yJmdUJVhUGS8ANZQwAAW0KCQrEjrW0toytDOnDx8GZssqjdQSAjMPgw5wOIg9xAQosK2lEA)